# how to automate scroll up using python selenium for below screen

Tags: python, selenium, scroll, scrollbar, frame

Need help in automating scroll up for the attached image or video

I am not able to attach video please help where  can share video

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiSQN.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.